# With SearchView (v7) keyboard is always visible?

Tags: java, android, searchview

I'm using SearchView in my activity and I see that when I change activity and then I return to the Searchview activity the keyboard opens by itself.

Here is my code:

```
       final android.widget.SearchView msearchView = (android.widget.SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_frontend);
       msearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        ...
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            return false;

        }


    });
```

How can I do to start the activity with hidden keyboard?

Edit: I don't want it iconized by default

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these attributes in the layout tag.

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it setting:

```
<SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:id="@+id/search_frontend"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:queryHint="Search..." />
```